# Sharing Ubuntu drives with Windows

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm new to the whole Linux thing. I have a Linux server up and running and have been using [this](http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/server-config/Samba.php) guide as a help. I have an issue with shared drives. My Windows machines can see them but can't write to them -- says I don't have permission. I'm completely lost.

Can anyone help? Let me know if I should post Samba configs. I'm running Windows XP, 7 and 8 and Ubuntu server.

Comment: I should say im using webmin to configure everything

Answer (score 2):

Samba share permissions are as held in it's configuration file `smb.conf` [`/etc/samba/smb.conf`]. Here you can set permissions such as:

- **guest ok**: If set to yes, the users will have access to the - share without
  having to enter a password. This can pose security risk.
- **writeable**: Specifies users should have write access to the share.

All of these settings use a simple `yes` or `no` setting.

Creating a shared directory to share your music and calling it `music`. Edit your `smb.conf` and add the following:

```
[music]
path = /home/shared/music
writeable = yes
```

If you are sharing the files on a large network and you don't want everyone to be able to write to the folder. You can also use `write list` and give users their own username and password instead of having it globaly `writeable`. You would define this as follows:

```
[music]
path = /home/shared/music
write list = mom dad fred
```

giving only those users the ability to write to the folder. There are many more options you could go with but this is the most straight forward. Check [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-samba-shares.html) for a more detailed tutorial on setting up permissions with shares in samba.

***NOTE:*** Once you're done editing the permissions make sure to restart Samba to apply the changes.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have already made sure they are set to writable and guest ok. its just for my home so don't really need to worry about security. any other ideas?

Comment: You've restarted the Samba server as well ? Also, the permissions set in the samba configuration does not take priority over the filesystem. So if you've done everything else set the permissions to the shared folder to 777. `chmod -R 777 /home/shared/movies` and restart the server and retest.

Comment: yeah rebooted samba server. so in my case it would be chmod -r 777 /media/films ?

Comment: If that's the actual directory then it would be owned by root and only root would have permission to do anything to it. So yes, you'll have to make it globally read & writable.

Comment: awesome :) ill try it when I get home and update you guys. Cheers for all the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: I recently had very similar problems.  Make sure the sticky bit is not set on the files/directories you want to share.  If the sticky bit is on ("1"), then you will be able to read, but not to write over Samba. To set the sticky bit off ("0"), you can run the `chmod -R 777 /path/to/shared/directory` command @cinelli suggested above.