# Is it possible to share an external hard drive through server?

Tags: centos, file-sharing

I was wondering if it is possible to share an external hard drive in CentOS server?

Comment: How would you like to share you external hard drive?

Comment: I just want it to be like a file server. Just where users on the same network can go read/write/delete files. Pretty much what my file server is doing. I just ran out of space on my server hard drive.

Comment: cross platform or just Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 2):

Once you plug the external HDD into your CentOS system it's effectively a local disk from which you can share it. If you're sharing it to other Linux systems then you're better off using NFS. If however you're sharing it to Windows systems, then Samba would be a better choice.

If you look around the U&L site, searching for Samba you'll find many Questions & Answers on the topic. For example: [Sharing ubuntu drives with windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67544/sharing-ubuntu-drives-with-windows). Don't let the name fool you, it isn't that Ubuntu specific.

A more detailed tutorial can be found on the CentOS website, titled: [SAMBA Setup](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba).

There are also tutorials for setting up NFS on the CentOS websites as well, titled: [18.6. NFS Server Configuration](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-export.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you recommend to start learning centos. I know there is plenty of documentation out there. What would you recommend? I just started learning linux and want to become a system administrator. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user44550 - http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ to get the background knowledge of Linux.  Good howtos - http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/linux/centos. For beginners - http://beginlinux.com/server/centos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, and there are many, many, many (did I say many?) ways to do so. My personal favorite is [Samba](http://samba.org/) because of its integration with Windows.

Comment: Is there a link I could look up to do this? I am able to share my computer by following the tutorials. I just can't find how to share my external hard drive. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba)?  You'll need to mount your external drive and figure out the mountpoint. I believe that setting up the shares is covered in the third step. You can skip setting up the extra partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ultimately you can, you have to use SAMBA if you want to share this hard drive (or any other directory) with Windows or MAC system.  However, once you connect the external HDD into the server, you have to mount this HDD into your system. However, you can use NFS as well for sharing Unix to Unix system. I'd recommend to google about SAMBA sharing and NFS in Linux.